# Best approach to test scope chains in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, scope, mocking, stub

In all my ruby on rails app, I try to not use the database in controllers, since they should be independent from persistence classes. I used mocking instead.

Here is the example for rspec and rspec-mock:

```
class CouponsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @coupons = Coupon.all
  end
end

require 'spec_helper'
describe CouponsController do
  let(:all_coupons) { mock } 
  it 'should return all coupons' do
    Coupon.should_receive(:all).and_return(all_coupons)
    get :index
    assigns(:coupons).should == all_coupons
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

But what if controller contains more complex scopes, like:

```
class CouponsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @coupons = Coupon.unredeemed.by_shop(shop).by_country(country)
  end
end
```

Do you know any good approach for testing simillar scopes chains?

I think that the following test does not look really good:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe CouponsController do
  it 'should return all coupons' do
    Coupon.should_receive(:unredeemed).and_return(result = mock)
    result.should_receive(:by_shop).with(shop).and_return(result)
    result.should_receive(:by_country).with(country).and_return(result)
    get :index
    assigns(:coupons).should == result
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `stub_chain` method for that.

Something like:

```
Coupon.stub_chain(:unredeemed, :by_shop, :by_country).and_return(result)
```

Just an example.

Comment: Yeah, but if you use stub_chain it won't fail when someone deletes this code and uses other kind of methods to achieve result.

Answer (score 0):

With `rspec > 3` use this syntax:

```
expect(Converter).to receive_message_chain("new.update_value").with('test').with(no_args)
```

instead of `stub_chain`.

Read more about message chains [in the documenation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains).